# Ajuda com Struct e Manipulação de arquivos em (C)

Tags: c, struct

Olá, preciso que vocês me ajudem...
Fiz esse algoritmo para cadastrar as "entrevistas" dos funcionários, e sempre que eu quiser buscar um funcionário, eu simplesmente coloco o nome dele e todos os dados referente a ele aparecem.
O programa está funcionando corretamente, porém, o "arquivo.txt" que no meu caso é "resposta.txt" está salvando como BINÁRIO...(E está com uns símbolos estranhos)...
helppp

CODIGO:

```js
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>


typedef struct contato CONTATO;
struct contato{
    char    nome[30];
    char    sexo[15];
    char    idade[5];
    float   renda;
    char    fumante[5];
    char    esportes[5];
    char    atividadef[5];
};

void cabecalho();
void cabecalho2();
void inputCTT();
void pesquisar();

int main(){

        int opcao;

        do{
                cabecalho();
                scanf("%d", &opcao);

                switch (opcao){
            case 1:
                inputCTT();
                break;
            case 2:
                pesquisar();
                break;

            case 3:
                printf("--------------------\n");
                printf("Volte sempre! =D \n");
                printf("--------------------\n");
                getch();
                break;

            default:
                printf("-----------------------\n");
                printf("Opcao invalida...\n");
                printf("-----------------------\n");
                getch();
                break;
            }
        }while (opcao != 3);

}

void cabecalho(){
    system("cls");
            printf("\n\t\t\t\t ALCATRAZ LTDA\n");
            printf("\t\t\t------------------------------\n");
            printf("\t\xC9\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xBB\n");
            printf("\t\xBA Para realizar uma nova entrevista: Digite [1]            \xBA\n");
            printf("\t\xBA                                                          \xBA\n");
            printf("\t\xBA Para realizar uma busca no banco de dados: Digite [2]    \xBA\n");
            printf("\t\xBA                                                          \xBA\n");
            printf("\t\xBA Para sair: Digite [3]                                    \xBA\n");
            printf("\t\xC8\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xCD\xBC\n");
}
void cabecalho2(){
            system("cls");
            printf("\n\t\t\t\t ALCATRAZ LTDA\n");
            printf("\t\t\t------------------------------\n");
}

void inputCTT(){


        FILE* resposta;
        CONTATO ctt;

        resposta = fopen("resposta.txt", "a");

        if (resposta == NULL){
            printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo...\n");
        }
        else{
            do{
                    cabecalho2();


                    fflush(stdin);
                    printf("\n");
                    printf("Nome: ");
                    gets(ctt.nome);


                    fflush(stdin);
                    printf("Sexo: [Masculino] / [Feminino] / [Outro]: ");
                    gets(ctt.sexo);

                    fflush(stdin);
                    printf("Idade: ");
                    gets(ctt.idade);


                    fflush(stdin);
                    printf("Renda: ");
                    scanf("%f", &ctt.renda);


                    fflush(stdin);
                    printf("Fumante: [Sim/Nao]: ");
                    gets(ctt.fumante);



                    fflush(stdin);
                    printf("Gosta de esportes:  [Sim/Nao]: ");
                    gets(ctt.esportes);


                    fflush(stdin);
                    printf("Pratica atividade fisica: [Sim/Nao]: ");
                    gets(ctt.atividadef);

                    fwrite(&ctt, sizeof(CONTATO),1, resposta);



                printf("\n\nDeseja continuar: [S/N]?\n");
            }
            while(getche() != 'n');

                fclose(resposta);
        }

}

void pesquisar(){
    FILE* resposta;
    CONTATO ctt;
    char nome[30];

    cabecalho2();

    resposta = fopen("resposta.txt", "rt");

    if (resposta == NULL){
        printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo...\n");
    }else{
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Digite o nome a pesquisar: ");
        gets(nome);

        while(fread(&ctt, sizeof(CONTATO), 1, resposta)==1 ){
                if (strcmp(nome, ctt.nome)==0){
                    printf("\nNome: %s\n", ctt.nome);
                    printf("Sexo: %s\n", ctt.sexo);
                    printf("Idade: %s\n", ctt.idade);
                    printf("Renda Mensal: %.f\n", ctt.renda);
                    printf("Fumante: %s\n", ctt.fumante);
                    printf("Gosta de esportes: %s\n", ctt.esportes);
                    printf("Pratica atividade fisica: %s\n", ctt.atividadef);
                }
        }

    }
    fclose(resposta);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Eu usei o CODE::BLOCKS.
Eu só precisava que o "resposta.txt" estivesse legível...

Comment: Você quer que `resposta.txt` possa ser lido pelo bloco de notas, por exemplo?

Comment: Ele já está sendo lido.
Porém estava como binário...
Mas a solução abaixo foi muito responsiva, obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na hora de escrever no arquivo, o `fwrite(&ctt, sizeof(CONTATO),1, resposta)` está passando por todas as posições dos vetores, inclusive aquelas que não foram preenchidas. Esses símbolos estranhos são esses espaços vazios, lixo de memória ou que sinalizam o fim da string.

Troque o comando citado acima por `fprintf`, que procura uma string dentro do vetor do char, em vez de escrever tudo que está nela.

```
// Dentro da função inputCTTT(), após ler as entradas
fprintf(resposta, "%s\n%s\n%s\n%f\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", ctt.nome, ctt.sexo, ctt.idade, ctt.renda, ctt.fumante, ctt.esportes, ctt.atividadef);
```

Após registrar duas pessoas, por exemplo, seu arquivo `resposta.txt` ficará parecido com isso:

```
Joao // Início do primeiro registro
Masculino
23
1234.56
Nao
Sim
Nao
Maria // Início do segundo registro
Feminino
32
6543.21
Sim
Nao
Sim
```

Para procurar os dados no arquivo com essa formatação, você pode usar o `fscanf`, porém, caso o nome não seja encontrado na linha atual, você deve pular 7 linhas (a linha do nome já foi lida para comparação), onde se encontar o próximo nome:

```
// Dentro da função pesquisar(), após ler o nome (a ser pesquisado)
while (1){
    fscanf(resposta, "%s", &ctt.nome); // Lê o nome no arquivo
    if (strcmp(nome, ctt.nome) == 0){
        fscanf(resposta, "%s %s %f %s %s %s", &ctt.sexo, &ctt.idade, &ctt.renda, &ctt.fumante, &ctt.esportes, &ctt.atividadef);
        printf("\nNome: %s\n", ctt.nome);
        printf("Sexo: %s\n", ctt.sexo);
        printf("Idade: %s\n", ctt.idade);
        printf("Renda Mensal: %.f\n", ctt.renda);
        printf("Fumante: %s\n", ctt.fumante);
        printf("Gosta de esportes: %s\n", ctt.esportes);
        printf("Pratica atividade fisica: %s\n", ctt.atividadef);
        break;
    } else {
        // Move o ponteiro do arquivo 7 linhas
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 7) {
            if(feof(resposta)) { // Fim do arquivo
                printf("Nome nao encontrado");
                fclose(resposta);
                getch();
                return;
            }
            if (fgetc(resposta) == '\n')
                i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, obrigado.
Funcionou quase que perfeitamente, porém, ele não está achando o segundo nome...
Quando eu procuro o 2º nome salvo ou o 3º nome salvo, ele não aparece nada.
Então eu pressiono [ENTER] e volta para o menu principal (Cabeçalho)

Comment: Estranho, pois o único jeito de sair desse loop ou é achando o nome (pelo `break`) ou no `if(feof(resposta))` (pelo `return`), onde há um `printf("Nome nao encontrado")`. Porém no seu não aparece nada? Aqui está funcionando normalmente

Comment: Cara, acabei de consegui.
O "erro" está ali no sinal.

While (i < 7) = Errado!
While (i >7) = Certo!

Muitoooo obrigado. =D

Comment: Que bom haha, a propósito adorei o seu cabeçalho/menu!

Comment: kkk, obrigado.
É para um trabalho da Fac...